# Need to understand, after the retun statement why it will back to the second line

Tags: java

```
public class CoreTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(goFigure(60));
        }

    public static int goFigure(int x)
    {
    if (x < 100)
     x = goFigure(x + 10);

    return (x - 1);
    }
}
```

The above is the java code, There is JAVA method named goFigure(). I called this method from main method. Here I am getting the output as 95.

I debug this code but facing doubt i.e after the execution of return statement it will go to the `x = goFigure(x + 10)`. Need to understand why it will go that line.

Please let me understand the concept.

Comment: its called _recursion_ google it

Comment: [Click me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Comment: @MarounMaroun [You're doing it wrong :P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625050/need-to-understand-after-the-retun-statement-why-it-will-back-to-the-second-lin#comment38163285_24625050)

Answer (score 2):

```
     goFigure(60)
         goFigure(70)
             goFigure(80)
                 goFigure(90)
                     goFigure(100)
                     return 99
                 return 98
             return 97
         return 96
     return 95
```

Every call having its own parameter x (and possibly local variables).

So you reach 100 from 60, needing 5 recursive calls, 60 + 4 * 10 + 5 * -1 = 95